# Is it Possible to apply PHP strtotime() Function in an array input for type time

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, datetime, strtotime

Good Day guys is it possible to apply strtotime or date format to an array? I have an input with a type of [time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNZmy.png) and it is in array and I want to include am/pm but it only store [integer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Xsed.png) value from my input. Im having a problem on how can I apply a date format to my array input and make it 12 hours time format ?

My INDEX code

```
<div class="col-md-12">
<table id="table-field">
  <tr>                                                       
    <th>Section</th>
    <th>time_start</th>
    <th>time_end</th>
    <th>Day</th>
 </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="subject[]" class="form-control "></td>
    <td><input type="time" name="time_start[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Select time"></td>
    <td><input type="time" name="time_end[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Select time"></td>
    <td> <select type="number" name="day[]" class="form-control">
        <option value="" selected disabled>Select Day</option>
        <option value="Monday">Monday</option>
        <option value="Tuesday">Tuesday</option>
        <option value="Wednesday">Wednesday</option>
        <option value="Thursday">Thursday</option>
        <option value="Friday">Friday</option>
        <option value="Saturday">Saturday</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type= "button" class="btn btn-warning" name="add" id="add" value="Add"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Here is my php code:

```
  if(isset($_POST['sectionbtn']))
   {
     $section = $_POST['section'];
     $level_id = $_POST['level_id'];
     $stats = 0 ;
     $sql3 = "INSERT INTO std_section (year_level_id, section, stats) 
     VALUES ('$level_id', '$section', '$stats')";
     if ($db->query($sql3) === TRUE) {

        $sec_id= $db->insert_id;
        $subject =    $_POST['subject'];
        $time_start = $_POST['time_start'];
        $time_end =   $_POST['time_end'];
        $day  = $_POST['day'];
        
        $stime = $time_start;
        $etime =  $time_start;;

        
    foreach($subject as $key => $value)
    {

       $stime[]  = date('h:i a', strtotime($value));
       $etime[] = date('h:i a', strtotime($value));

         
        
        $save = "INSERT INTO std_subject(subject, time_start, time_end,section_id) 
        VALUES ('".$value."','". $stime[$key]."','".$etime[$key]."','$sec_id')";
        $done = mysqli_query($db, $save);    
    }
  }
 }
```

I want to store time in databse like this [sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsFo4.png)

Comment: Don't store time data in your database as an integer, or as a formatted string. Use the TIME or DATE TIME type and do the formatting when you display the data.

Comment: I just change the data type of my database into TIME and now I am getting a 0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000 value

Comment: I orginally use varchar as my data type because Im thinking of storing integer and string as I wanted to store a data like this ( 12:00 pm )

Comment: If you're getting `0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000` you're using datetime not time

Comment: I try both time and date time but i cant still store am/pm value